# Shell Script: To extract a part of string from a file after a match is found

Tags: shell-script

A script must be written to extract and return a string value from a file. This must be done only after a match is found in the file for the given pattern.

Example:

```
"id":"re454sv:57ghg34sfw:87wre56:rty4598gh"
```

This text is the sub part of a big log file and also many instances of this with `"id":"some value"` could occur.
I need to return that 'some value' portion every time and from a lot of files in that directory.

I think `sed` utility in Unix helps here, but I couldn't figure out ts exact usage. Would be glad if somebody could help.

Comment: is this json data?  if so, use `jq` or `jsonpipe` or a language with json-parsing libraries (e.g. `perl` or `python`).

Answer (score 1):

You're not clear on whether you want just the first `:` separated value or the whole remainder of the line after the `"id"` tag.

The former is:

```
sed -nre 's/^"id":"([^:]*):.*/\1/p' <file>
```

The latter is:

```
sed -nre 's/^"id":(.*)/\1/p' <file>
```

Note the switches are important. `-n` ensures that nothing is printed (with the `p` tail printing those lines that do match). `-r` enables extended regular expression parsing so things like brackets don't have to be escaped.

Comment: Brackets never have to be escaped.  Also `-E` is more portable than `-r` and does the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

`sed 's/"id":"\([^"]*\)"/\1/g'`

Extracts the value if you pipe it in via stdin

Comment: Please explain your answer.  Bare sed scripts are hard to understand, especially for a questioner who's not familiar with sed.

Comment: This does not "extract the value", it replaces the occurrence of the pattern `"id":"(...)"` with the part captured inside the parentheses, as in, piping text like `Alice: hello\n"id":"boom"\nBob: hi!` will come out of `sed` like `Alice: hello\nboom\nBob: hi!`.